# Termux closes window immediately on Android 10 and 11

Tags: android-10, termux, android-11

Since a few days I have problems with Termux on my Android devices.

On a Lenovo TB-X304F running Android 8.1.0 I got:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash": library "libandroid-support.so" not found

[Process completed (signal 6) - press Enter]
```

I was able to recover from this using the [procedure from the Termux wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Recover_a_broken_environment).

But on a Fairphone 3 running Android 10 and a Google Pixel running Android 11 the Termux window is immediately closed, even when I start it in a failsafe session. There is only a message saying "Termux keeps stopping".

I have removed Termux and reinstalled from F-Droid but to no avail. This is very unfortunate because I mostly use Termux on the Fairphone for quick webserver checks with `openssl` and `netcat`.

I checked the permissions (only Files and Media) and allowed them, but to no avail.

How can I get Termux running again on the newer devices?

**Update:**

According to [this comment](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/1896#issuecomment-764633391) the issue is only with version 0.105 and should be gone with 0.106.

Comment: Shouldn't F-Droid remove .105 from "suggested" state then, in favor of previous version .104? At least until the new release.

Comment: I am not connected to F-Droid except that I use it as a platform to download the Apps. The answer only describes a workaround until F-Droid replaces version 0.105.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that came with version 0.105 of Termux and should be gone with 0.106.

In the meantime this [workaround](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/1896#issuecomment-766188879) helped me to solve the problem with Android 10 and 11.

Basically it involves the following steps:

1. Install Termux
2. Get access to the home directory inside Termux (for instance with a file manager)
3. Create the directory */home/.termux*
4. Place an empty file named *termux.properties* inside of */home/.termux/*
5. Start termux